# How to add conditional styles in emotion/react?

Tags: reactjs, emotion

I'm using react and emotion. I need to change the style of an element according to a boolean value. The below code does not work. How can I combine multiple styles correctly?

```
import { css } from "@emotion/react"

const navSticky = css({
  transform: "translateY(-10px)",
})
const navStyle = css({
  background: "red",
})

... 

 <nav css={isSticky ? {...navStyle, ...navSticky} : navStyle}> </nav>
```

Comment: If using `className`, one is able to typically do something like this (using backticks): ``className={`${styles.style1} ${styles.style2}`}``. Don't know if thes ame should work here? May be it is worth a try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As first variant i suggest use styled component for this. Set background as base property and set transform if isSticky prop has been passed with true value.

As second variant i suggest correct your example. Use JSX Pragma with jsx function from '@emotion/react'. This allow use css prop. Docs: https://emotion.sh/docs/css-prop#jsx-pragma

```
// first variant

const Nav = styled.nav`
  background: red;
  transform: ${p => p.isSticky && "translateY(-10px)"};
`

const App = () => <Nav isSticky={true}>Some Elements</Nav>

// second variant

/** @jsx jsx */
import {jsx} from '@emotion/react'

const navSticky = {
  transform: 'translateY(-10px)',
}

const navStyle = {
  background: 'red',
}

const App = () => (
  <nav css={{...navStyle, ...(isSticky && navSticky)}}>Some Elements</nav>
)
```